# How to show a sibling parent div

Tags: jquery

I need to show a `<div>` but it's dynamic `<div>`. When I click on any `.info`, I want to show the parent first `<div>`.

Here is my code:

Html :

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div class="myBox">
     <p><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></p>
       Fist Div
  </div>

  <h5>Title <img src="info.gif" class="info"  /></h5>
  <div class="myBox">
    <p><a href="#" id="close">Close</a></p>
        Second Div
  </div>

  <h5>Title <img src="info.gif" class="info"  /></h5>

</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$('.info').click(function(e){

    var ppp=$(this);
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
    parentDiv.show('slow'); // doesn't work     
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamique" div?

Comment: And which div do you exactly want so show?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're clicking isn't a descendant of the div you want to show, so `parent().parent()` won't find it. It's the parent element's previous sibling, so ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ovitiy)):

```
$('.info').click(function(e){

    $(this).parent().prev('div').show('slow');

});
```

If you're adding/removing these divs (if that's what you mean by "dynamic"), then I'd use `delegate` to handle this at the `mainDiv` level ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ovitiy/2)):

```
$('#mainDiv').delegate('.info', 'click', function() {

    $(this).parent().prev('div').show('slow');

});
```

---

**Off-topic**: Your HTML is invalid, you've used the same `id` value ("close") on two different elements. `id` values **must** be unique on a page. In the live examples above, I've changed that `id` to a class and shown how to make it work in both the static and dynamic examples.